# List produces trash element

Tags: c, list, struct

My list is inserting 4 elements and at the end when i print it back produces this trash back
"└V│1634289500" as additional element, like it is 1 more node

This is the adding node function:

```
void insertlist( struct studente **lista, char *surname, char *name, int vote){
    //allocates a new node and fills with datas

    struct studente *newpointer = malloc(sizeof(struct studente));
    strcpy(newpointer->cognome, surname);
    strcpy(newpointer->nome, name);
    newpointer->voto = vote;

    // 
    newpointer->next = *lista;
    *lista = newpointer;
}
```

The list stores names and votes of students who tried an exam, and prints only who passed it with  a vote equal or higher than 18.

```
void prinfifpassed(struct studente *listastudenti){
    for(; listastudenti != NULL; listastudenti = listastudenti->next){
        if(listastudenti->voto >=18)    printf("%10s%10s%4d ESAME SUPERATO\n", listastudenti->cognome, listastudenti->nome, listastudenti->voto);
    }
}
```

Each time i run the program i dont get errors about inserting elements in my list, everything gets printed if i print everything, it just prints 1 line more with this "└V│1634289500" element, which was never inserted. I guess the error is in the for loop when i print, but i dont see it.

Comment: Provide a minimal program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to initialize the initial pointer to the head node by NULL as for example struct studente *lista = NULL;

Comment: exactly what vlad said, basic errors are always my worst enemy